# Which layer is Unix socket on?

Tags: networking, unix-socket

I am trying to use Unix Socket to implement IPC and I know that Unix Socket is much more faster than TCP, but I still have 2 questions.

1. Is Unix Socket reliable as TCP?
2. Which layer is Unix Socket on in OSI?

Answer (score 0):

1. Unix sockets are reliable like TCP, provided the sender and receiver keep participating.
2. A unix socket does not map to the OSI network socket layers. It is local only, between two processes on the same machine.